# Spring integration Java DSL: specify custom deserializer

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration

I have object which is transferred via JMS to a component which listens to queue via channel adapter:

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .destination(inputQueue)
                )
```

However this kind of setup only gives a possibility to receive `ObjectMessage` however I want to provide custom deserializer which will also be able to accept `BytesMessage`. The desired setup looks like this:

```
IntegrationFlows
                .from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                        .destination(inputQueue)
                        .deserializeWith((javax.jms.Message message) -> new org.springframework.messaging.Message(){}) // Does not exist, but desired
                )
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deserialization logic is a part of `org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter`, which you can specify as a :

```
.from(Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
        .destination(inputQueue)
        .jmsMessageConverter(...)
 )
```

I understand your wish to make that with the Lambda, but I don't see reason to introduce extra logic if that can be achieved with an existing abstraction.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Small question: when I do not specify it, is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter being used?

Comment: +1: `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jms/ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener.java#L72